# Unique constraints by subclass

Tags: grails

I currently have a set of domain subclasses that are mapped via table-per-hierarchy.  One of the attributes in the base class needs to be unique but only within each subclass.  My initial thought was to use the discriminator to create a multi-column unique constraint, something like this:

```
BaseClass {
   String name

   static constraints = {
       name unique 'discriminator'
   }
}
```

I get back the error:

```
Scope for constraint [unique] of property [name] of class [class BaseClass] must be a valid property name of same class
```

Is there a way to use the discriminator for this purpose or another way to go about setting a property unique per subclass?  Switching to table-per-subclass is not really on the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that was a harrowing couple of hours.  The above code was nearly right, just needed to be in each subclass and use the column name of the discriminator, which defaults to 'class'.

```
SubClass extends BaseClass {
    static constraints = {
        name unique: 'class'
    }
}
```